# How to set the timezone on NSDateComponents

Tags: objective-c, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to encapsulate a time using a `NSDateComponents`..but it give me 1979-05-10 08:30:00 +0000....what value should set for `setTimeZone:` to give me the Houres in my local time (GMT+2) which should be 1979-05-10 10:30:00 +0000

```
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comp setYear:1979];
[comp setMonth:5];
[comp setDay:10];
[comp setHour:10];
[comp setMinute:30];
[comp setTimeZone:];
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `+(NSTimeZone) timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:`. 
To convert hours to seconds, multiply by 3600.

**Examples:**

For GMT+2

```
[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:3600*2]
```

For GMT-2

```
[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-3600*2]
```

To get the timezone local to your device:

```
[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]
```

Comment: I put zero for `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT` not (3600*2) to get the correct time: 1979-05-10 10:30:00 +0000
Can please explain why?..is that the correct way to do this?:

`NSTimeZone *local = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
        NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [comp setYear:1979];
        [comp setMonth:5];
        [comp setDay:10];
        [comp setHour:10]; 
        [comp setMinute:30];
        [comp setTimeZone:local];`